# Java trying to change the JFrame title when method stops executing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to change the title of my JFrame when something stops happening how could i achieve this?

I have tried the following:

```
if(camera.isItDone() == false){
                    setTitle("Sending...");
                }else if(camera.hasFocus() == false){
                    setTitle("Communication");
                }
```

the 'isItDone' method returns a boolean variable and when false this prints 'sending' on the button click on action listener, however after it being done how can i update this to say communication? because it gets stuck on 'Sending'?

EDIT:

I have also got a Swingworker and then i execute this to run a method in camera, and then check is it done which is a boolean.

Comment: Looks like a good start, but maybe the problem is in the code you're not showing us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly; you don't compare a method that returns a `boolean` to a `boolean`. Like Ball.isRed() == false, Ball.isRed() already contains that value.

Secondly; check you if-cases in the debugger. If your are stuck on "Sending..." then:

1. Either `camera.isItDone()` is always `false`, or
2. `camera.hasFocus()` is never `true`.

Your if-else-case is built upon two different booleans that both have to match to fall in the right pigeon hole.